# Admin user has no authority to see settings and other aspect of the application

Tags: jhipster

I have created an app using Jhipster and after running backend with './mvnw' and frontend as 'npm start'.
And then I go to the login page
My authorities array is empty for the admin.
And due to that, it has no authority to see anything else and that's why I am getting an error as follows.

```
"You are not authorized to access this page."
My response.
activated: true
authorities: []
createdBy: "system"
createdDate: null
email: "admin@localhost"
firstName: "Administrator"
id: 3
imageUrl: ""
langKey: "en"
lastModifiedBy: "system"
lastModifiedDate: null
lastName: "Administrator"
login: "admin"
```

Any help will be appreciated

It should the settings and active sessions page.

Comment: Please don't crosspost with Github issues and provide required details.Why tagging with jhipster-registry?

Comment: Apologies.
I have removed jhipster-registry.

Comment: Solved!!! Just had to restart it a couple of times. And it works.